# How to encode characters like ä, ö, ü from HTML to python?

Tags: python, html, dataframe, character

I would like to import tables from Wikipedia to my Jupyter Notebook and then put their content into a dataframe.

Problem: Special characters like the German ä, ö, ü or French é, è are not encoded correctly. How do I parse an HTML with these characters correctly?

This is the source page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ski_areas_and_resorts_in_Switzerland

And there is my code:

```
#!conda install -c conda-forge wikipedia --yes
import wikipedia as wp
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
import numpy as np

#Import page
html = wp.page("List_of_ski_areas_and_resorts_in_Switzerland").html().encode("UTF-8")

#Create Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
df.head()
```

This is the output. As you can see, the Resort "Champéry" is written as "ChampÃ©ry".

[image]

I helped myself by replacing them manually.

```
#Clean
df = df.replace(to_replace ="Ã¶", value ="ö", regex=True) 
df = df.replace(to_replace ="Ã©", value ="é", regex=True)
df = df.replace(to_replace ="Ã¨", value ="è", regex=True)
df = df.replace(to_replace ="Ã¼", value ="ü", regex=True)
```

**My question is**: isn't there a better solution to just import characters correctly from a website?

Comment: Either don’t `encode` the text, or use the `encoding` parameter…? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: from unicode import unicode; uncode("Champéry") - this help to overcome encoding issues